# Reset teamcity.build.id?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Is it possible to reset the teamcity.build.id value in teamcity?

I'm able to reset the build.counter value easily in the build configuration, but I haven't found anything to reset teamcity.build.id.

Comment: Why do you need to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to reset build id, because it is used to identify related records in database storage. Resetting it would ruin your build history.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from TeamCity 8.0 build IDs are editable, so you can assign whatever value you want (of course they must be unique).
It provides you also a "Bulk Edit" feature.
More info [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/What%27s+New+in+TeamCity+8.0#What%27sNewinTeamCity8.0-HumanFriendlyIdentifiers).

Comment: According to your link these ids are only for "projects, build configurations, templates and VCS roots". The OP wanted to reset the id of the build itself. This is not possible and probably won't ever be possible (see @Nikita 's answer)